# Poetry configuration is invalid - Additional properties are not allowed ('group' was unexpected)

Tags: python, python-poetry

Recently, I faced this issue with Poetry. All my commands using poetry were failing with the following error.

```
RuntimeError

  The Poetry configuration is invalid:
    - Additional properties are not allowed ('group' was unexpected)
```

Comment: Check that you use the correct poetry virtual environment. Just had the same issue and deleting the .venv directory and running poetry install again resolved the problem.

Comment: poetry seems to break backwards compatibilty every other version, I would steer clear of it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I figured out the following issue.

1. The code owners had updated the poetry core requirement to `requires = ["poetry-core>=1.2.0"]`
2. My current poetry version was `1.1.12`

I did the following to fix my issue.

```
# remove the current poetry installation
rm -rf /Users/myusername/.poetry

# upgrade poetry version
pip install poetry -U
```

This should solve the problem. I verified the same by running my other poetry commands.

> It should be noted that your current poetry configurations will be lost while doing this, and would need to be recreated and reinstalled.

```
# reinstall poetry for my project
poetry install
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, I had installed poetry using apt, so I issued the command apt remove python3-poetry to remove poetry, then I installed it using the command pip install poetry -U. The instructions at https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1.2.0/ did not work for me.

Answer (score 15):

This is because you're working on a repo that uses the [new version of Poetry, >=1.2.0](https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1.2.0/) and you may have the old poetry installed locally.

The new version of `pyproject.toml` file supports dependency `groups` such as the following example

```
[tool.poetry.group.new_group]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.new_group.dependencies]
tensorflow = "*"
```

The solution is to update your version of Poetry using the instructions in the [poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1.2.0/).

Answer (score 0):

For me just doing `conda decativate` worked. It turns out that i was by default in a "base" enviroment with the wrong installation of poetry