# Poetry configuration error when adding Meltano tap-csv extractor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry, meltano

I'm attempting to add the tap-csv extractor to my Meltano project in a virtual environment but run into the following error when running `meltano add extractor tap-csv`:

```
RuntimeError
  The Poetry configuration is invalid:
    - Additional properties are not allowed ('group' was unexpected)
```

I have tried the installation instructions in this ReadMe too but still get the same error. I initially was on Poetry 1.15.X but now have switched to 1.2.0a1 as I thought perhaps the addition of groups in the new version of Poetry may have been the error but had no luck.

For reference I checked out [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876790/poetry-configuration-is-invalid-additional-properties-are-not-allowed-group) as well but had no luck.

Comment: Hi Danial. The version of Poetry in your system should not affect installation of packages from direct git references (the case of tap-csv for Meltano), so I'm guessing it's some quirk about how you installed Meltano. 

Can you share your Meltano version, Python version and operating system?

Comment: I'm on meltano version 2.20.0, Python 3.6, and RHEL 8